# How can I make my slidebar keep position through refresh

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I am having a trouble with my slidebar, because when i reload the page it goes to his originally possession. I need it to store some value in session in php or something but I can not find any way for it to work, If the slidebar is closed on refresh I need it to be closed when the page load, but if the slidebar is open before refresh I need the sldiebar to be open whe the page load.

PHP:

```
<div id="sidebar" style="transform: translate(<?php
if($_SESSION['slide'] == 0) {
    echo '-100';
} else if($slide == 1) {
    echo '0';
} else {
    $_SESSION['slide'] = 0;
}
?>%,0);">
```

CSS:

```
#sidebar {
position:fixed;
width:25%;
min-width: 350px;
height:100%;
left: 0px;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-top:40px;
overflow:hidden;

font-family:  "helveticaneue", "helvetica-neue", "helvetica", "lucida grande", "arial";
color: 444444;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var state = true;
$('#sidebar_button').click(function() {
    if(state) {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(-100%,0)');
        state = true;
      }
   });
});
```

I need some clever way to work around it becaus I need the session to change when I click on `<div id="sidebar_button">`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use a cookie or localStorage.  LocalStorage is preferred, and easier to work with, but check the browser support first to make sure it meets your requirements.  Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var state = localStorage.getItem('sidebarState') === "on";

function setState() {
    if(state) {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(0,0)');
        state = false;
    }
    else {
        $('#sidebar').css('transform', 'translate(-100%,0)');
        state = true;
   }
   localStorage.setItem('sidebarState',state ? "on" : "off");
}

$('#sidebar_button').click(setState);

setState();

});
```

Comment: This dosn't support closing the slidebar

Comment: When the slidebar is open and I click the button it doesn't close

Comment: There is still one error, on reload the slidebar shows always up open

Comment: var state = localStorage.hasOwnProperty('sidebarState') ? localStorage.getItem('sidebarState') : false; Doesn't work right

Comment: Sorry, saw your other post about this and noticed the bug.  Chris was correct in his answer.  Edited for clarity.